# How to pass categorical features to Linear Regression modeling in PySpark MLlib?

Tags: python, pyspark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib, categorical-data

I was working on `Linear Regression` modeling in `PySpark` and have a doubt regrading that. The data that I have has `categorical features`. I went through the documentation on `PySpark` and the example for `Linear Regression` shows this:

```
model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData)
```

It does not show how to pass the `categorical features` to `Linear Regression`. I have worked on `Random Forest` in `PySpark` before where I first `encoded` `categorical features` and then passed these features to the model as `Random Forest` provides a `parameter` to specify the `categorical features`. The `Linear Regression` does not show any such parameter in the documentation.

Can anyone help me by providing me the way to pass `categorical feature` to `Linear Regression` modeling in `PySpark` `MLlib`

Answer (score 7):

You need to use a '''VectorAssembler''' to build a "features" column. "features" is the default name of the features column so in the univariate case you do `LinearRegression(featurescol="catvar")`. Here is a walkthrough of the whole process, assuming you started with `strVar` in a dataFrame `df`.

**Step 1:** Build an index that maps to the string variable.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

varIdxer = StringIndexer(inputCol='strVar',outputCol='varIdx').fit(df)
df = varIdxer.transform(df)
```

**Step 2:** Encode the categorical variable as a sequence of binary variables using a `OneHotEncoder`

```
df = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="varIdx", outputCol="varCat").transform(df)
```

**Step 3:** Create the "features" col using a `VectorAssembler`.

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["varCat"],outputCol="features")
df =  assembler.transform(df)
```

**Step 4:** Fit the model (I have only tested with LinearRegression).

```
lr = LinearRegression(labelCol='y',featuresCol='features')
```